# The endpoint is not avalible in production mode

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I'm learning the basics of `Chrome DevTools`, and I've got the task where I need to get access to the linked information, but when I click on the link I've got an error:

> "this endpoint is not avalible in production mode" page

I've tried to find something using `Devtools`, but vainly.

I'm a complete newbie, where should I search?

[here is the task itself](http://acme.cyberschool.msu.ru/)

Comment: To get help you need to provide more details, see [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Devtools won't help you to debug the problem because it happens on the server. The `flag` link on that page points to a nonexistent URL.

Comment: ok, so is there anything i could do about that?

Comment: It's impossible to say based on the details you provided. If it's your server there then you should debug it.

Comment: no, it`s not mine. That`s everything i got, this is my hometask, but no explanations about it were given, only the link, so I kinnda have no idea on how should i deal with it